# Can I move unsupported utilities—like JDK8—into homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, jdk

Maybe I'm clutching at straws and/or misunderstanding the whole Homebrew idea, but:

I need JDK8 in homebrew, which isn't available anymore to Homebrew due to some licensing issues [e.g., https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/issues/7253 ]; JDK9 and newer cause a cascade of errors. However it still is available (after clicking and "agree with T&Cs") directly from Oracle, and installs no problem.

So my last hope is: Is there a way to somehow move this working JDK8 into my 'homebrew ecosystem'?

Comment: What about using [OpenJDK](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk) instead?

Comment: @JakeGould I did that but it doesn't seem to have much effect: I keep running into a scala/sbt "[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: not a type: symbol" which I gather implies Java9-or-higher is in use.